# Count string frequency in a 2D list

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say, i have a data like:

```py
x = [['stack', 'over', 'flow'], ['stack', 'stack', 'flow']]
```

How can I have a pd data frame that counts each string such that output is like this:

```
       count
stack   3
over    1
flow    2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is your list guaranteed to be 2-dimensional? Is there any particular reason why you need that output as a DataFrame or Series? You are aware that `x` as it is currently defined is _not_ a Series, right?

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.Series.explode` (available from `pandas` >= 0.25):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(x, name='count').explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
stack    3
flow     2
over     1
```

In case of using lower version of `pandas`, use `collections.Counter` with `itertools.chain`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

pd.Series(Counter(chain(*x)), name='count')
```

Output:

```
stack    3
over     1
flow     2
```

Note: `Counter` method seems 6x faster

```
%timeit pd.Series(Counter(chain(*x)), name='count')
# 151 µs ± 3.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit pd.Series(x, name='count').explode().value_counts()
# 755 µs ± 11.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Just discovered ```explode()``` deals nicely with deeply nested data, while the ```Counter``` method crashes if any unpacked element is itself a list. Try for example ```y = [[['stack'],'over','flow'],['stack',['stack']]]```.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @neutrino_logic How does it deal nicely with deeply nested data? Calling `explode()` on the example you gave seems to leave certain lists intact.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It doesn't throw any exceptions or crash the program - just treats the lists like any other element. The counter method in contrast crashes on an unhashable exception.

Comment: @neutrino_logic You're right, it may not be perfect, but that is definitely an advantage!

Answer (score 2):

I will do

```
pd.DataFrame(x).stack().value_counts().to_frame('count')
Out[10]: 
       count
stack      3
flow       2
over       1
```